# onOpen not working on Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a piece of code to work when the spreadsheet is open. I added the onOpen script, set the script trigger to "when spreadsheet is open", and waited for....nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

The script basically copies a row from one sheet to another based on the value of a cell. I want the script to copy all the rows that have the specified value to the next sheet only when the sheet

```
function onOpen(){
 moveThisRow();
 }

function moveThisRow(){

 var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 7; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "move it";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Sheet2";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var fill = sheet.getActiveRange-2;


  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Help!

Comment: Open the execution transcript (View > Execution transcript). Is there an error in that log? If so, what is it?

Comment: This line returns NaN  var fill = sheet.getActiveRange-2;   The 'getActiveRange()' method returns an instance of the Range class. If you'd like to offset the range or perform other actions with it, you must use Range methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually running correctly. The problem is the conditions in your `if` statement are never getting met. I've added a `else` section to your code with an alert to more easily show this.

```
function onOpen(){
  moveThisRow();
 }

function moveThisRow(){

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 7; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "move it";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Sheet2";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
//  var fill = sheet.getActiveRange - 2;

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Conditions are true')
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Conditions are false')
  }
}
```

If you update your `onOpen` function to create a menu with the code below, you can see that when the conditions you specify are actually met, the code is doing what you've told it to.

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Test')
      .addItem('Run', 'moveThisRow')
      .addToUi();
 }
```

Additionally, as pointed out earlier above, your `fill` variable is NaN but that doesn't cause a problem since it isn't actually used in the code anywhere (I just commented it out). Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dan! Thanks for the help. I ran the script as you modified and saw the genius of what you did! It did return a "conditions are false" as predicted. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the "getactiverange" method which works superbly when the script is run onEdit but doesn't work with onOpen. The question then becomes how can I reference the column of interest (ie. column 7) precisely using getRange as opposed to using getActiveRange. Also, would this require modifying the code to loop through the rows and execute if the value in the row is the value of interest?